# Returning Derived templated class as Base class pointer

Tags: c++

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static Base* construct() {
        return new Derived<T>();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
};
```

That code generates a compile error (VS Studio 2017):

```
syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'
```

Is this invalid C++? Is this pattern not possible?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c

Comment: While you may be slightly different because of the template part of your question, the answers are pretty close to thos found at [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes). Thus, I'm flagging as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare `Base` as:

```
class Base {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static Base* construct();
}
```

Then declare `Derived`:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
};
```

Then define `Base::construct`:

```
static Base* Base::construct() {
    return new Derived<T>();
}
```

The compiler needs a full definition of `Derived` before it can deal with the `new` in `Base::construct`.

Answer (score 0):

Try forward declare class Derived before Base.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived;

class Base {
//...
};
```

The compiler doesn't know what is `Derived` in `return new Derived<T>()` as it is declared afterwards.
`

Comment: You can only have things like pointers for forward declared classes, not `new` statements. It needs to know the `sizeof` for starters.

Answer (score 0):

Either split the declaration and implementation:

```
class Base {
public:
    static Base* construct();
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
};

template<typename T>
Base* Base::construct() {
    return new Derived<T>();
}
```

Or use the template magic:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base {
public:
    static Base* construct() {
        return new Derived();
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base<Derived<T>> {
public:
    Derived() {}
};
```